# Triangle inequality not making sense in this problem.

Tags: geometry, inequality

I'm working through "An Introduction to Inequalities" by Bellman and Beckenbach. They're discussing the path of a reflected ray of light, and they make a statement that seems kind of un-intuitive to me.

Consider the three points in the plane P, Q, and R such that:

$P:(0, a)\\Q:(q, b)
\\R:(r, 0)$

R lies between P and Q.

The authors state that vis-a-vis the triangle inequality,

$\sqrt{a^2+r^2}+\sqrt{b^2+(q-r)^2}\ge\sqrt{(a+b)^2+q^2}$

To me though, if we use the plain english version of the triangle inequality, that is, the sum of the lengths of any two sides of a triangle is greater than or equal to the length of the third, we should get this:

$\sqrt{a^2+r^2}+\sqrt{b^2+(q-r)^2}\ge\sqrt{(b-a)^2+q^2}$

I'm aware that the triangle inequality states that:

$\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}+\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2}\ge\sqrt{(x_1+x_2)^2+(y_1+y_2)^2}$

And by this definition, the authors' statement makes perfect sense. However, from a geometric standpoint, I just can't seem to make heads or tails of this. Can someone sort this out for me?

Comment: From a geometric standpoint, the ray was reflected in $R$. Reflect the part of its path after it hit $R$ in the $x$-axis, and the distance it travelled is the same as if it went from $(0,a)$ via $(r,0)$ to $(q,-b)$.

Comment: Agree, a direct application of the triangle inequality gets your result Josh.  They must be making some assumption statement about $Q$ being reflected about the $x$ axis.  It's hard to say more without directly checking the text itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @DanielFischer' idea, I have the following picture drawn:-
[image]

Applying triangle inequality, we then obtain the stated result:-

$\sqrt{a^2+r^2}+\sqrt{b^2+(q-r)^2}\ge\sqrt{(a+b)^2+q^2}$

That is, there is nothing wrong with the author's quote.

Comment: @Josh Recently, While re-visiting some of the posted questions, I found yours. The solution comes a bit late but hope it still helps.